# MDX : how to calculate number of months between a date and beginning of the year?

Tags: date, mdx, iccube, mdx-query

Using iccube, I want to calculate the number of months between a date and the beginning of the year.

I have 2 hierarchies in my date dimension :
`[Date de sortie].[Année, semestre, trimestre, mois, jour]` : contains Year, half-year, quarter, month and day
`[Date de sortie].[Année et Mois]` contains Year and month

executing the following mdx returns me the good result (5 months)

```
with 
set myData as {[Date de sortie].[Année et Mois].[Mois].&[2017-01-01]:[Date de sortie].[Année et Mois].[Mois].&[2017-05-01]} 
member nbMonths as  myData.count
select
{
    nbMonths
} on 0,
myData on 1
from [Cube]
```

But, when trying to parametize this, it uses a period beginning with the first date with data instead of beginning the period with the calculated date (1st day of year).

```
with 
calculated member beginOfYear as dtWithDayOfYear(lookupByKey([Date de sortie].[Année, semestre, trimestre, mois, jour].[Jour], [Date de sortie].[Année et Mois].[Mois].&[2017-05-01].key),1).key
set myData as {lookupbykey([Date de sortie].[Année et Mois].[Mois], beginOfYear):[Date de sortie].[Année et Mois].[Mois].&[2017-05-01]} 
calculated member nbMonths as  myData.count
select
{
    nbMonths, beginOfYear
} on 0,
myData on 1
from [Cube]
```

[image]

...

[image]

As result you can see above, beginOfYear seems to be calculated correctly, but not used in the set myData. So, it returns 113 instead of 5.

Answer (score 0):

It might be complicated using only MDX, one option is using the Java interface in icCube

This would be stright forward by declaring a function that takes two dates and use Joda library :

```
Function NumberOfMonth( Value date1 ,Value date2 ) as
            abs(J!org.joda.time.Months.monthsBetween(date2, date1)->getMonths() )
```

The code would look like :

```
WITH 
  FUNCTION NumberOfMonth( Value date1 ,Value date2 ) as abs( J!org.joda.time.Months.monthsBetween(date2, date1)->getMonths() )
  MEMBER Diff as NumberOfMonth( [D. Time].[H. Time].[Day].&[2015-03-02].key, [D. Time].[H. Time].[Day].&[2015-10-02].key )
SELECT
 [Diff] ON 0
FROM [Sales]
```

------- 8 Mar 2018 -------

Don't forget to switch on Java module and set the classRepositoryActive to true (the latest if a bug that will be fixed in the next release)

Comment: I just tried your solution and get an error : la classe de la méthode 'J!'!'org.joda.time.Months.monthsBetween est inconnue : 'org.joda.time.Months'

Comment: By the way, maybe my question was already too oriented, because what I want is to calculate "full-time equivalent" month per month on a hierarchy containing different types of personnels and do the same on a range of months, or years, which becomes an average, maybe I don't need to know the number of months, and there is a simpler solution...

Comment: Regarding the error have you checked that JAVA support has been enabled : https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx_integration/java_integration.php

Comment: in the .xml, I have : <javaMdxConfiguration active="true">  <classRepositoryPath>java.class.path</classRepositoryPath>  <allowedPackage>org.joda.time</allowedPackage>
 <allowedPackage>org.joda.time.Months</allowedPackage>    Still getting the same error

Comment: Can you send use the call stack and be sure the server was restarted. What icCube version are you using (ideally joda-timeXXXX.jar file name)